# How to fix UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am communicating with `pysimplegui` but I am having the `UnboundLocalError` within one of my functions.

Here is the `function`:

```
def load_file(file):
    file_details = file.split('.')
    
    if file_details[1] == "csv":
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        
    elif file_details[1] == "xlsx":
        df = pd.read_excel(file)
        
    elif file_details[1] != "csv" and file_details[1] != "xlsx":
        sg.popup("Unsupported file type")
    
    else:
        sg.popup("Your file does not meet the requirements", "Please check the file requirements for more info")
        
    return df
```

What could be wrong with my code?

Comment: It seems to me that would happen on your second `elif` or the `else`, because there is no `df` object being assigned in those cases. Also `file_details[1] != "csv" and file_details[1] != "xlsx"` seems redundant with the previous conditions.

Comment: How do you recommend I fix this?

Comment: return inside the ifs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only create an object named `df`, if the details are either "csv" or "xlsx". If they have another type, no `df` will be created. Hence, you can not return df at the end of your function. It will crash, whenever you try.

There are two possibilities:

- Return df only if it exists by returning it out of the if-elif-block.
- Create a df without any values if the file type is invalid.

Option 1:

```
def load_file(file):
    file_details = file.split('.')
    
    if file_details[1] == "csv":
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        return df
        
    elif file_details[1] == "xlsx":
        df = pd.read_excel(file)
        return df
        
    elif file_details[1] != "csv" and file_details[1] != "xlsx":
        sg.popup("Unsupported file type")
    
    else:
        sg.popup("Your file does not meet the requirements", "Please check the file requirements for more info")
```

Option 2

```
def load_file(file):
    file_details = file.split('.')
    
    if file_details[1] == "csv":
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        
    elif file_details[1] == "xlsx":
        df = pd.read_excel(file)
        
    elif file_details[1] != "csv" and file_details[1] != "xlsx":
        sg.popup("Unsupported file type")
        df = None
    
    else:
        sg.popup("Your file does not meet the requirements", "Please check the file requirements for more info")
        df = None
        
    return df
```

With both options, the function will return `None` if the type is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the empty variable before any condition like the following

- df = ''

def load_file(file):
file_details = file.split('.')

```
 **df = ''**

if file_details[1] == "csv":
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    
elif file_details[1] == "xlsx":
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    
elif file_details[1] != "csv" and file_details[1] != "xlsx":
    sg.popup("Unsupported file type")

else:
    sg.popup("Your file does not meet the requirements", "Please check the file requirements for more info")
    
return df
```